# Automatically run macro when opening workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I have not used VBA at all and was wondering if anyone could help me with automatically running a macro when opening a workbook? I get an error when opening the workbook stating:

> "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Here is the code I tried:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    GetUserName = Application.username
End Sub
Function GetUserName()
    GetUserName = Application.username
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you are wanting to achieve, but this perhaps?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").value=GetUserName
End Sub
Function GetUserName()
    GetUserName = Application.username
End Function
```

Comment: I want the username to appear in a cell within the workbook, not as a msgbox. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @asnf21395 - you didn't say that, I've amended the code.

Comment: I just tried the new code but the cell isn't changing. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Works for me. Have you definitely put the Open code in the ThisWorkbook module?

Comment: Yeah, it is pulling the user name but it isn't automatically updating when I reopen the workbook.

Comment: Well if it's you opening it each time I guess it won't change!

Comment: I change the username in order to test if it will automatically update but it does not.

Comment: You're closing the file and re-opening it? it works for me when I change the username via Excel Options.

Comment: Yeah I am. I change the username in Excel Options and then close and reopen the workbook but the cell does not change.

Comment: Check that macros are enabled. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Does it matter if cells are merged?

Comment: Don't see why it should, but that is something you can test yourself.

Comment: It is working but it is appearing in a different sheet even when I change the code to the desired sheet.

Comment: My code used sheet code names so you might want to use the actual sheet name, e.g `Sheets("Sheet1")...`

Answer (score 1):

To the solution above - the code can be shorten to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Application.UserName
End Sub
```